# Hdri is not showing in 3D view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, world

I've been using blender 2.8 for past two weeks but I can't use HDRI image as environment if I apply that I'm only getting a  color[image]

Answer (score 4):

In the World Options, select Environment Texture for Color and then select Hdri Image.

In the shader node, we attach the hdri image to the color in the background node.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, using PNG instead of JPG fixed a magenta background when I tried this